# Error ArgumentNullException was unhandled

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I am referring this http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=585 to retrieve image from sql server to window phone and had error ArgumentNullException was unhandled when run it at the that higlighted row.

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            byte[] buffer = value as byte[];
            **Stream memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);**
            WriteableBitmap wbimg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memStream);
            return wbimg; 
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null; 
        }
    }
```

I had found another similar post had same error with me.
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/74224/452127.aspx
But don't understand the coding..Anyone know how to solve the error?

Comment: It's exactly what the exception says. `buffer` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like **value** is null or is not a byte array.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    WriteableBitmap wbimg = null;

    if (value != null && value is byte[]) {
        byte[] buffer = value as byte[];
        Stream memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        wbimg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memStream);
    }

    return wbimg; 
}
```

Comment: But when i add
if ( value != null&& value is byte[] )
in my coding. It show me error not all code paths return a value..

Comment: I try already. The value is null..I think may be because the prob is at the part to convert image. I use this [http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/] to insert image into sql server. Can you help me have a look at the coding. I am still trying to understand both coding..